Why are MALDI and DESI the most popular mass spectrometry imaging instruments?
I have reading some reviews about mass spectrometry imaging (MSI). There are some techniques including: secondary ion mass spectrometry (SIMS), laser desorption ionization (LDI), laser ablation eletrospray ionization (LA-ESI), matrix-assisted laser desorption ionization (MALDI), and desorption electrospray ionization (DESI). Some of them also have high spatial resolution and even not need matrix. But it seems MALDI and DESI are the most popular techniques for MSI. What are the main reasons?
